# Get the number of entries in a bib-file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, counters

I need to know how many entries are in my `.bib`-file.

It seems like using a sort of counter is pointless since there are different refsections and publications appear in various refsections.

In the example below I would expect the number "4" for four publication entries in the `.bib`-file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,
  author          = {A Author},
  keywords        = {A1},
}

@article{B,
  author          = {B Author},
  keywords        = {A2},
}

@article{C,
  author          = {C Author},
  keywords        = {A2,A3},
}

@article{D,
  author          = {D Author},
  keywords        = {A1,A3},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage[%
  style         = ext-numeric,
  backend       = biber,
  defernumbers  = true,
 ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
There are in total 
    XX 
publications. 

\newcommand\crcbib[1]{%
  \begin{refsection}
    \section{Project #1}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[%
      resetnumbers = true,
      heading = none,
      keyword = {#1},
    ]
  \end{refsection}
} 
\crcbib{A1}
\crcbib{A2}
\crcbib{A3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count anything in the `.bib` file from LaTeX, you can only count the entries that actually make it to the `.bbl` file. (If `\nocite{*}` has been used, you will get all entries from the `.bib` in the `.bbl`, so this can be less of a concern. You can't, however, differentiate by file, if you have multiple `.bib` files. There are workarounds for that, but there is no official solution.)

Since you have multiple refsections, you can't just increase a counter for every item in the `.bbl` file with `\AtDataInput`. But you can increase a counter for every entrykey you haven't seen before.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  style        = ext-numeric,
  backend      = biber,
  defernumbers = true,
 ]{biblatex} 

\newcounter{totalbibentries}
\newcommand*{\listcounted}{}

\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \xifinlist{\abx@field@entrykey}\listcounted
    {}
    {\stepcounter{totalbibentries}%
     \listxadd\listcounted{\abx@field@entrykey}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,
  author          = {A Author},
  keywords        = {A1},
}
@article{B,
  author          = {B Author},
  keywords        = {A2},
}
@article{C,
  author          = {C Author},
  keywords        = {A2,A3},
}
@article{D,
  author          = {D Author},
  keywords        = {A1,A3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
There are in total 
    \thetotalbibentries\
publications. 

\newcommand\crcbib[1]{%
  \begin{refsection}
    \section{Project #1}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[%
      resetnumbers = true,
      heading = none,
      keyword = {#1},
    ]
  \end{refsection}
} 
\crcbib{A1}
\crcbib{A2}
\crcbib{A3}
\end{document}
```

[image: There are in total 4 publications.]

---

Note that this may still not result in the expected output in case your bibliography uses features that involve entry cloning, such as `related`. In that case we may have to guard the counter with a `\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}` to skip entries that would be skipped in the bibliography

```
\AtDataInput{%
  \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
    {}
    {\xifinlist{\abx@field@entrykey}\listcounted
      {}
      {\stepcounter{totalbibentries}%
       \listxadd\listcounted{\abx@field@entrykey}}}%
}
```

or explicitly filter cloned entries

```
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifundef\abx@field@clonesourcekey
    {\xifinlist{\abx@field@entrykey}\listcounted
      {}
      {\stepcounter{totalbibentries}%
       \listxadd\listcounted{\abx@field@entrykey}}}
    {}%
}
```

I'm sure one could come up with more pathological example here. So it all depends on your setup.

Comment: outstanding answer! First solution is absolutely enough for me.

Comment: is it possible to get the number of entries a `\printbibliography` would render? Even when a filter is used?

Comment: @moewe Is there a counter when I only need to get the number of entries in the bbl file?

Comment: @Intolighter I don't think so (to be fair, `biblatex` has lots of features and from time to time I forget about some of them). You'll have to count them "yourself" like shown here. There might be other edge cases as well, where it might be more appropriate to "count closer to where the entries are processed/printed" in `begentry` or some such, but that depends on your exact use case, setup and requirements.